# how to access changed attributes after fetch? backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm using this code to fetch a model from a server:

```
var id = args.model.get('id');
var options = { 
    action: 'getSubscriber', 
    address: args.model.get('address'),
    silent: true
};

new Subscriber({ id: id }, options).fetch({
    success: function(model, response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(model);
    }
});
```

the `response` object contains all the data I need whereas `model` stores the data not as its direct attributes but as `changed` object. Is it wrong? 
Usually I access model attributes with help of `model.get('name')` call. How do I access fresh attributes in that case? Should it be `model.changed.thePropertyIwantToAccess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `change` event

```
    this.model.on('change', function () {
        var changedAttributes = this.model.changedAttributes();
        //Process the changed attributes
    }, this);
```

Bind this events in the `initialize` function of the View

Comment: Is that a normal behavior?

Comment: normal means it is documented feature/process of the given API. Or it is sorta hack?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this:

```
var Subscriber = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: null,
        name: null,
        status: null
        // ...
    },
    initialize: function(attributes, options) {
        var _this = this;
        this.options = options || {};                
        this.on('change', function() {
            _this.set(_this.changedAttributes()['0']);
        });
    }
// ...
```